# fragment inside fragment with tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need your help in a program from my job. I have a tab with two graph(mpandroidchart), and this not support other graphs in the same layout(lose vertical scrollbar), I fixed this, put in a fragments  and its work when swipe in tabs, but when i press other tab and back, the program crash, i really need your help, i read that cannot inflate a fragment inside fragment, I put the fragment in xml not dinamically. In the other tabs have a google maps fragment and other graphs

Here is my code

layout that containt two fragments

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="1800dp"
android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
tools:context=".General_evolIP">


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1173dp">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1800dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp">

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView"
              android:layout_width="352dp"
              android:layout_height="78dp"
              android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:text="Evolucion Indicadores Productivos"
              android:textSize="30sp" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView8"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
              android:text="Nº Peces vivos por region"
              android:textSize="15sp" />

          <fragment
              android:id="@+id/fragmentFishAlive1"
              class="com.ctwings.aquareport.fishAlive"
              android:layout_width="200dp"
              android:layout_height="200dp"
              android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
              android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
              tools:layout="@layout/fragment_general_evol_i" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView2"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
              android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
              android:text="Peso Cosecha Mensual por Especie"
              android:textSize="15sp" />


          <fragment
              android:id="@+id/fragmentFishHarvestWeight1"
              class="com.ctwings.aquareport.harvestWeight"
              android:layout_width="200dp"
              android:layout_height="200dp"
              android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
              tools:layout="@layout/fragment_general_evol_i" />


          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewgraphHeight"
              android:layout_width="255dp"
              android:layout_height="35dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/fragmentFishHarvestWeight1"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
              android:layout_marginBottom="242dp"
              android:text="Mortalidad Mensual"
              android:textSize="15sp" />

          <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
              android:id="@+id/graphMortalityMonth"
              android:layout_width="774dp"
              android:layout_height="240dp"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
              android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />
          -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and this is my error

```
06-02 11:10:42.814 5537-5537/com.ctwings.aquareport E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.ctwings.aquareport, PID: 5537
                                                                  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                      at com.ctwings.aquareport.General_evolIP.onCreateView(General_evolIP.java:38)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1430)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:732)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:503)
                                                                      at com.ctwings.aquareport.DashboardActivity.setupDefaultPager(DashboardActivity.java:85)
                                                                      at com.ctwings.aquareport.DashboardActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(DashboardActivity.java:182)
                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:151)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
                                                                      at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:318)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                      at com.ctwings.aquareport.General_evolIP.onCreateView(General_evolIP.java:38) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1430) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:732) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:503) 
                                                                      at com.ctwings.aquareport.DashboardActivity.setupDefaultPager(DashboardActivity.java:85) 
                                                                      at com.ctwings.aquareport.DashboardActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(DashboardActivity.java:182) 
                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:151) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958) 
                                                                      at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:318) 
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201) 
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #41: Duplicate id 0x7f0d00bf, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.ctwings.aquareport.fishAlive
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2293)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                      at com.ctwings.aquareport.General_evolIP.onCreateView(General_evolIP.java:38) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1430) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:732) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025) 
                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:503) 
                                                                      at com.ctwings.aquareport.DashboardActivity.setupDefaultPager(DashboardActivity.java:85) 
                                                                      at com.ctwings.aquareport.DashboardActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(DashboardActivity.java:182) 
                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:151) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958) 
                                                                      at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:318) 
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201) 
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

I really apretiated your help
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that your nested `Fragment` layout contains a `View` with the same id has another `View` in the the host `Fragment` layout?

This would cause an error because you have two Views with the same id in the `ViewGroup` tree.

Your getting this error discription:

> Binary XML file line #41: Duplicate id 0x7f0d00bf, tag null, or parent
>   id 0xffffffff with another fragment for
>   com.ctwings.aquareport.fishAlive

which sugests that.